# How can I run the Android Emulator in Android Studio without opening Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to open/run an emulator that was created from `avdmanager` without having to open Android Studio? i.e. Having a start menu shortcut that starts the emulator, without Android Studio opening. I know that `avdmanager` is not totally dependent on Android Studio, because it is possible to close it while the emulator is running.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps in [developer description](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline).

Under Windows the emulator is installed in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\emulator` The created images are located under `C:\Users\<username>\.android\avd`.

Example PowerShell:

```
C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\emulator> .\emulator.exe -list-avds                            
Nexus_5X_API_23_arm
Nexus_5X_API_23_x86

C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\emulator> .\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5X_API_23_x86
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Navigate to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`.

2.) Make a shortcut with  `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator -avd "EMULATOR NAME"` being in the location.

In order to find the emulator names run `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator -list-avds` from command prompt.